# Unable to retrieve access token from authorisation code for Azure app

Tags: node.js, access-token, adal, passport-azure-ad

I am doing SSO to Azure AD for my Azure app using passport-azure-ad library. Following is the options object :

```
const options = {
    identityMetadata: process.env.AZUREAD_IDENTITY_METADATA,
    clientID: process.env.AZUREAD_AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    responseType: 'code id_token',
    responseMode: 'form_post',
    redirectUrl: process.env.AZUREAD_REDIRECT_URL,
    allowHttpForRedirectUrl: true,
    clientSecret: process.env.AZUREAD_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
    validateIssuer: false,
    issuer: null,
    passReqToCallback: true,
    useCookieInsteadOfSession: true,
    cookieEncryptionKeys: [
        { key: '********************************', iv: '************' },
        { key: '********************************', iv: '************' },
    ],
    scope: ['profile', 'offline_access', 'https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read'],
    loggingLevel: 'info',
    nonceLifetime: null,
    nonceMaxAmount: 5,
    clockSkew: null,
};
```

After getting authorisation code (req.body.code) from the AD callback, I am using that to retrieve access token for my app using adal-node library. Relevant code snippet -

```
const authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(
            `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com`,
        );
        authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode(
            req.body.code,
            process.env.AZUREAD_REDIRECT_URL,
            process.env.AZUREAD_AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
            process.env.AZUREAD_AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
            process.env.AZUREAD_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
            function(err, response) {
                let message = '';
                if (err) {
                    message = 'error: ' + err.message + '\n';
                }
                message += 'response: ' + JSON.stringify(response);

                if (err) {
                    console.log(message);
                    return;
                }
...
```

But this method is resulting in following error:

```
"error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token.\r\nTrace ID: 539cdaf3-460d-43fa-b4bb-6f23a8058800\r\nCorrelation ID: 507aafd9-5a4a-4417-b1f8-9fe4a5bc4cd3\r\nTimestamp: 2020-02-28 13:10:27Z",
    "error_codes": [
        54005
    ],
```

Also tried retrieving access token based on documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-authorization-code-to-request-an-access-token) using Postman, but that also results in same error.

Kindly help me to figure out the mistake here.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Azure AD will no longer accept authorization codes to issue tokens that have already been used.

You need to get a new Authorization code every time. Also, you can change your code to request a refresh token that will be passed to /used by additional resources as the refresh tokens can still be reused.

Reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4192e141-309a-4dd6-a5c9-f1a8ce32f4ca/aadsts54005-oauth2-authorization-code-was-already-redeemed